# What password or key does salt-cloud use to login to a newly created OpenStack VM minion?

Tags: openstack, rackspace-cloud, salt-stack

I'm using salt-cloud with Rackspace OpenStack cloud severs.
I've setup the provider and a profile without explicitly setting any key or password settings. When I issue the command to create a new vm e.g.

```
salt-cloud -p profile vmname
```

the machine gets created quite happily and salt-cloud appears to be logging in repeatedly to perform the initial configuration and bootstrapping the minion.
My questions is how is it logging in? With which details? And how I could I find them and login to minion manually myself after it's been created by salt-cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked it out myself. The answer is it used password authentication.
I created a vm with debug level logging and the generated password is output.

```
salt-cloud --log-level debug -p profile vmname &> outputfile
```

Searching the output file gave this line:

```
...
221 [DEBUG   ] Using ************ as the password
...
```

(221 is the line number added by vim)

Using that password I was able to login to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Salt-cloud queries the openstack api for the root password of the new vm and uses that to log in.

You can then use Salt to set a new password.